# Basis exchange property proof without use of rank and span

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

I want to prove that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are distinct bases in a matroid $M$ then for any $y\in B_2$ where $y$ is not also in $B_1$ there exists $x \in B_1$ where $x$ is not also in $B_2$, such that $B_1-x+y$ is also a base of $M$.

I have found similar proofs but they all use terms like span and rank and I must not use any of these definitions in the proof.

I know that $B_1+y$ is not an independent set, since $B_1$ is inclusion wise maximal. And $B_1-x$ is an independent set. I am trying to argue if there must exist a $y$ in $B_2$ so that $B_1-x+y$ is independent and also a basis since it has the cardanality of $B_1$. But I am stuck at this moment.

Comment: $B_1 - x$ is an independent set with fewer elements than $B_2$, so there exists $y$ in $B_2$ (and not in $B_1 - x$) extending $B_1 - x$ to an independent set. If this doesn't answer your question I think you need to be clearer about what axioms you are using.

Comment: What is the definition of a matroid which you are working from?

Comment: @MarkWildon  I thought we could not be sure that adding $y$ to $B_1-x$ would mean that all subsets of $B_1-x+y$ would also be in $I$ ($M=(E,I$)).

Comment: @MarkWildon, I realise now that this is exactly what defines the exchange property of a matroid

Comment: You say you want to prove this... What makes you confident that it is true?  And why are you not willing to use the notions of span or rank in your proof?

Comment: @LouisDeaett So it is an assignment I got from school. And we are supposed to be able to solve the assignments with the definitions we have been provided, rank and span not being among them. Maybe I need to make this clear in my posts? I am new here and not so familiar with how to correctly use this forum.